# Returning in query whether a column has been changed by the current query or not

Tags: postgresql, update, postgresql-13

I have a query like

```
UPDATE my_table 
  SET my_value = 
    CASE WHEN random() > 0.5 THEN my_value * 2 ELSE my_value END
RETURNING *;
```

Now, inside the `RETURNING` statement I'd like to have a boolean indicating whether `my_value` has been changed by the current query or not.

Let's assume, I cannot pass the previous value of `my_value` as a param to the query.

So, is there a way to obtain something like a list of columns which have different values after the `UPDATE`? Or get the values at the state before `UPDATE` in `RETURNING`?

In my example, I could, of course, put the result of `random()` in a CTE like

```
WITH random_cte AS (
    SELECT random() AS my_random
)
UPDATE my_table 
  SET my_value = 
    CASE WHEN my_random > 0.5 THEN my_value * 2 ELSE my_value END
FROM random_cte
RETURNING *, my_random > 0.5 AS value_changed;
```

But that would bloat the query somewhat up. So I'm wondering if I could do that in a more elegant way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two queries are **not equivalent**. The first query would evaluate the **`VOLATILE`** function `random()` for every row, while the second evaluates it once in the CTE, so `my_random` is the same for all rows.

And no, the CTE won't be inlined. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html#id-1.5.6.12.7)

> However, if a `WITH` query is non-recursive and side-effect-free (that is, it is a `SELECT` **containing no volatile functions**) then it can be folded into the parent query

Bold emphasis mine.

But that's probably just an accident in the construction of your test.

Either query updates all rows, even if nothing changes.

To get your `value_changed` reliably, compare pre-`UPDATE` with post-`UPDATE` values:

```
UPDATE my_table t
SET    my_value = CASE WHEN random() > 0.5 THEN t.my_value * 2 ELSE t.my_value END
FROM  (SELECT id, my_value FROM my_table) pre
WHERE  t.id = pre.id
RETURNING t.*, t.my_value IS DISTINCT FROM pre.my_value AS value_changed;
```

`id` being the PK or any other (combination of) unique not-null column(s).

`random() > 0.5` can be `true` and `my_value` still unchanged. Think of `NULL` or `0`.

There is a potential **race condition under concurrent write load**. See:

- [Return pre-UPDATE column values using SQL only](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7927957/939860)

If your use case is really that simple (only a single column to be updated), you'd rather suppress empty updates to begin with. See:

- [How do I (or can I) SELECT DISTINCT on multiple columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12632129/939860)