# Do I need an explicit FOR UPDATE lock in a CTE in UPDATE?

Tags: postgresql, update, locking, cte, postgresql-13

In Postgres 13, I have a table which gets updated frequently. However, the update query is rather complicated and uses the same values multiple times. So, using a CTE seems quite a logical thing to do.

A simplified example looks like this:

```
WITH my_cte AS (
    SELECT
          my_id,
          CASE WHEN my_value1 > 100 THEN 50 ELSE 10 END AS my_addition     
    FROM my_table      
    WHERE my_id = $1
)
UPDATE my_table
        SET my_value1 = my_table.my_value1 + my_cte.my_addition,
            my_value2 = my_table.my_value2 + my_cte.my_addition
FROM my_cte
WHERE my_table.my_id = my_cte.my_id
```

Now I'm wondering: What would happen if between the `SELECT` in the CTE and the `UPDATE`, the table is updated by another query, changing `my_value1` on thus, the calculation of `my_addition` were to become outdated and wrong when the `UPDATE` happens. Can such a situation occur? Or does Postgres set an implicit lock automatically?

If Postgres does no magic here and I need to take care of it myself: Would it be sufficient to do `FOR UPDATE` in the `SELECT` of the CTE?

Sorry if I did not make myself clear here: It's not that I want to "see" those concurrent modifications, I want to prevent them i.e. once the calculation the `SELECT` is done, no other queries might modify that very row till the `UPDATE` is done.

In real life, what I mocked here by `CASE WHEN my_value1 > 100 THEN 50 ELSE 10 END` is about 20 lines long and I need it at about 5 places in the `UPDATE`. Since I'm a big fan of "Do not repeat yourself", I think a CTE is the way to go. Or is there a better way to avoid copy & pasting in an `UPDATE` without a CTE?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Postgres uses a multiversion model ([Multiversion Concurrency Control, MVCC](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/mvcc-intro.html)).

In default [`READ COMMITTED` isolation level](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/transaction-iso.html#XACT-READ-COMMITTED), each separate query effectively sees a snapshot of the database as of the instant the query begins to run. Subsequent queries - even within the same transaction - can see a different snapshot if concurrent transactions are committed in between. (Plus what has been done in the same transaction so far.)

However, as far as [CTEs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html) are concerned, all sub-statements in `WITH` are executed concurrently with the outer statement, they effectively see the same snapshot of the database. All of it is considered a **single query** for this purpose.

So, **no**, you don't need an explicit lock to stay consistent.

Encapsulating the logic in a function may be convenient for a number of reasons, but that has no effect whatsoever on concurrency. Aside: a CTE with a **volatile** function is never inlined. See:

- [Returning in query whether a column has been changed by the current query or not](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/308436/returning-in-query-whether-a-column-has-been-changed-by-the-current-query-or-not/308442#308442)

A `SELECT` does not lock queried rows. Postgres allows concurrent `UPDATES`. But `UPDATE` locks target rows. Concurrent transactions trying to write also, have to wait until the locking transaction has finished.

If you want to forbid writes to rows (columns) that have only been selected from while your `UPDATE` is in progress, you may want to take locks anyway (or use a stricter isolation level). Maybe [`FOR UPDATE` locks, or maybe a weaker lock](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-FOR-UPDATE-SHARE). That depends on details and requirements you are expressly withholding / not giving in your question.

Also (though you did not ask for that), if multiple concurrent transactions may be writing to overlapping rows (more than one at a time), be sure to adhere to the same, **consistent order of rows** to [**avoid deadlocks**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/curent/explicit-locking.html#LOCKING-DEADLOCKS). That typically requires `ORDER BY` before locking.

If columns contributing to that `ORDER BY` might be updated by concurrent transactions, you also need to add [`NOWAIT`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-FOR-UPDATE-SHARE) to be be sure. Locking happens after `ORDER BY`. If a concurrent transaction updates a row in between, Postgres waits till that transaction is finished. If committed, the row may now sort differently, and the lock would happen out of order, re-introducing the possibility for deadlocks. So `NOWAIT` is the only way to be sure in `READ COMMITTED` isolation level. Or use a stricter isolation level. `REPEATABLE READ` or `SERIALIZABLE` would raise a serialization failure in that case anyway.

Comment: Just on your last comment, would you ensure consistent ordering by adding `ORDER BY` and `FOR NO KEY UPDATE` to the CTE?
In a similar vein, I've been wondering if using a CTE is necessary when updating using `FROM (VALUES` to prevent deadlocking https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/322808/does-update-from-values-lock-rows-in-the-order-they-are-listed/322816

Comment: @ChrisJ: Adding `NO KEY` is just a weaker lock, that may make sense if your `UPDATE`s do not alter key columns. (Else Postgres will escalate to a `FOR UPDATE` lock eventually anyway). `ORDER BY` plus `NOWAIT` are essential to be absolutely safe from deadlocks. And yes, a CTE is typically necessary. See: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/69497/3684

Comment: Thanks. I'm confused by the need for `NOWAIT` and have a follow up question https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/323040/avoiding-deadlocks-when-locking-multiple-rows-without-using-of-nowait

Answer (score 1):

If you want to prevent concurrent statements from modifying the rows that the CTE selects before they get updated, you need to use `SELECT ... FOR NO KEY UPDATE` in the CTE.

Comment: Hm, this differs from the accepted answer. Let's imagine the above query in session A & another `UPDATE` in session B. Are you pointing to the fact that while OP's sel+upd queries are executed concurrently in A, if Postgres requires a seq scan, the lock will be applied gradually as it progresses through the dataset to update rows; thus creating a gap where an `UPDATE` in session B could update a row that session A has not yet gotten to? Then, if B's `UPDATE` still keeps the row returnable by the `WHERE` filter exp, session A would then *'incorrectly'* overwrite the row - is that right?

Comment: Locks *are* taken row by row, but the problem is something else. It is true that the `SELECT` and the `UPDATE` share the same snapshot, but if the `UPDATE` is blocked, it will re-evaluate the row and may find it changed, that is, different from the version in the snapshot it shares with the `SELECT`. See [this article](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/transaction-anomalies-with-select-for-update/) for an example. It shows what I mean for `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE`, but the principle is the same. Typically Erwin's answers are well researched and better than mine, but he missed something here

Comment: I see - what’s the point of the FOR UPDATE then, if you’re using REPEATABLE READ? Either way, if something has been updated, you’ll get a serialisation failure. Using REPEATABLE READ would give you optimistic locking.

Comment: The `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` would lock the rows, so that there can be no concurrent modifications and consequently no serialization errors. But sure, using `REPEATABLE READ` and *not* using `FOR UPDATE` would also solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Building on what [a_horse_with_no_name](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/1822/a-horse-with-no-name) said:

> I would put such a condition into a (SQL) function. Another alternative to locking (if you expect this to occur rarely) would be to use the `serializable` isolation level and re-run the UPDATE if an error occurs.

Put the addition logic into a function, and then call that function each time you went to set a new value. This will help you in two ways.

1. This allow you to avoid duplicating the addition logic each time you use it.
2. This makes for a very simple update statement that can get in quick, lock just a few rows, and get out.

Something like this should work.

```
CREATE FUNCTION fn_my_addition(my_value int)
RETURNS INT
LANGUAGE SQL
AS
$$
  select CASE my_value1 > 100 THEN 50 ELSE 10 END;
$$;

UPDATE my_table
SET my_value1 = my_value1 + fn_my_addition(my_value1),
    my_value2 = my_value2 + fn_my_addition(my_value2)
WHERE my_id = $1;
```

Comment: What if `fn_my_addition` takes several seconds? In a CTE solution, it's executed only once. In your solution it's at least called multiple times, I don't know if Postgres does some caching here.

Comment: @cis The function should be very fast. It's not reading any data from the database. It's simply taking an input parameter and doing a CASE on it. No different than if you did the same CASE on the data, inline in the update.

Comment: As mentioned several times, `CASE my_value1 > 100 THEN 50 ELSE 10 END` is just a placeholder for a MUCH more complicated expression which I cannot and don't want to show - because it's not my question.