# Does UPDATE FROM VALUES lock rows in the order they are listed?

Tags: postgresql, locking, deadlock

I'm bulk updating some rows using `UPDATE ... FROM (values ...` as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18799497).

Will the rows will be locked in the order that they appear in the values? Or do I need to do an explicit `SELECT FOR UPDATE` first?

Here's an example statement

```
UPDATE stats as t set "individualCount" = new_values."individualCount"
  FROM (values (6::int,7::int),(3::int,15::int))
  as new_values("individualCount","id") 
  WHERE new_values."id" = t."id"
```

(id is the primary key of the table)

Answer (score 0):

The order in which rows are locked is not guaranteed. You could use `EXPLAIN` to see the execution plan, which will reveal what the database does. But don't rely on an execution plan: changes in the data can lead to PostgreSQL choosing a different execution plan.

The only reliable way to lock rows in a certain order is to run `SELECT ... FOR NO KEY UPDATE NOWAIT`. `NO KEY` is only to avoid taking a stronger lock than you need, and `NOWAIT` is important to make sure that the order is correct: without it, rows that are concurrently modified may be returned in a different order.

You can use a CTE to have the `SELECT ... FOR NO KEY UPDATE` be part of the `UPDATE` statement.

Comment: Thanks. The behaviour you describe for `NOWAIT` does not seem to be in the documentation? https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html Based on the docs it seems purely for avoiding waiting, it doesn't mention that it will impact ordering and deadlock avoidance

Comment: Oh sorry, I misread. It's not related to locking but rather the warning about READ COMMITTED mode where rows may come back in a different order

Comment: Right. If you don't wait for the lock, the row cannot have changed since you took the snapshot.